# STM32 UART Receive Not Functioning

Tags: stm32, esp8266, uart

I am passing data between an ESP8266 and an STM32F411RE. I am receiving UART data in IT mode, code here :

```
uint8_t rx_data[10];
int counter = 0;

int main(void){ 

< INIT FUNCTIONS REMOVED>
HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &rx_data, 5);

while(1){
HAL_Delay(1000);
printf("COUNTER IS %d \n", counter);
}
}


void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {
    if (huart == &huart1) {
    counter++;

    }
    memset(rx_data, 0, sizeof(rx_data));
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, &rx_data, 5);
}
```

I am sending 5 lettered string to STM from my ESP8266, code :

```
#define BUF_SIZE (1024)


int sendData(const char* rdata)
{
    const int len = strlen(rdata);
    const int txBytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_0, rdata, len);
    return txBytes;
}

static void echo_task()
{
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    // Configure parameters of an UART driver,
    // communication pins and install the driver
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 74880,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity    = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE
    };
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_0, &uart_config);
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_0, BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);

    while (1) {
    
            vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            if(button_is_pressed)
            {
             sendData("RECVD");
            }
     

    }
}

void uart_main()
{
    xTaskCreate(echo_task, "uart_echo_task", 1024, NULL, 5, NULL);
}
```

When I run the program on my STM, I receive either gibberish on my rx_data and counter immediately goes to three digits like 175 or 204, immediately after reset, before the ESP8266 is even connected to the STM board. Once the ESP is connected and button is pressed, the counter jumps 100 or 200 digits everytime I receive data and it prints gibberish like 0m . What can be going wrong?

Also : I am able to send data from STM32 and receive on Esp without issue, so UART settings seem to be fine.

Comment: I don't see you setting the baud rate in the first chunk.  And 74800 is not a standard baud rate.  Maybe try 57600 and see if that works.

Comment: I tried changing the Baud rate to 57600 and my code (on the esp side) would just blow up everytime. I don't know whats wrong, I changed only the baud rate in the main.c and the sdkconfig files. I change it to 74880 and it works okay again.

Comment: Have you tested UART on each device with PC? Connect both devices to PC and use serial terminal program. The way it is now, you have too many variables at play, it would be hard to pinpoint the source of the problem. Verify with PC that ESP sends stuff correctly, and then fix the STM receiver with PC serial communication. Make sure printf doesn't conflict with anything, it could be changing some UART configs behind the scenes, fighting with the interrupt receive function over UART registers